# Unable to open file because startup disk is full

Tags: mac, hard-drive, microsoft-excel, memory, disk-space

I was trying to open my excel file from my disk-based thumb drive when i got the following error message

[image]

I proceeded to  make space on my hard drive by emptying my recycle bin and deleting some stuff permanantly before i could open my excel file from my disk based thumb drive.

Why do i have to make space on my startup drive before i could open my excel file , I thought the file would be temporary stored in my RAM and executed from there . The file size is at max 30KB , I am sure it can be stored on RAM

Comment: Sarfari will create a temp file on your hdd even if you "open" the file.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of swap-files.  OSX like Windows uses actual files in the file system to extend the base-ram of the system.  Essentially, bits of RAM that aren't currently being used can be temporarily written to disk and then re-read back into RAM on-demand.  Your disk-based thumb-drive probably does not have enough space to accommodate the swap-files.  (and storing swap files on flash... is a very bad idea.)

You can disable the swap-file usage, but doing so would require that you have sufficient RAM to load everything your computer runs without it.

You can read more information here:

http://osxdaily.com/2010/10/08/mac-virtual-memory-swap/

Comment: I did not include linux/*nix in this category, because they typically use a swap partition rather than files in the file-system.

Comment: "Your disk-based thumn drive probably doesnt have enough space ", my disked based thumb drive has excess space , more than 2GB available , i dont think your arguement stands

Comment: 2gb of free space... is too little for swap.  My argument is correct, and the error indicated above is exactly what you would see.  Try disabling swap or moving the swap folder... and see what you get from there.